# Simple inheritance but confusing

Tags: java

This is class JavaTest

```
package testing.test;

public class JavaTest 
{
    int i=2;
}
```

This is class JavaTest2 , which extends JavaTest

```
package testing.test;

class JavaTest2 extends JavaTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        new JavaTest2().add(5);
    }

    void add(int i)
    {
        System.out.println(5+i);
    }
}
```

Now the output is coming to 10  , actual problem is get the i value of parent class to add..

Comment: There is no any complex logic. You just print 5+5...

Comment: @Anand nobody born knowing all these stuff. For example, if you post a JSF question, you will look like a noob compared to [BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc), but no need to be rude with nobody (at least not in this site).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza , question is changed , have a look , i cannot post more question , and also upvote if possible to allow me post new questions...but i need explanation u did last time , you explain well

Comment: You must not edit an already answered question. Instead, create a new one and post a link referring to this one. Also, the questions are open for everyone to read and answer, not just for a single person.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i am not allowed to post more questions :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *thing* here is that your `add` method **shadows** the `i` attribute of the class with the `i` variable declared as parameter. Thus, when using `i` inside `add` method, you're using the `i` parameter, not the `i` attribute.

To note the difference, change the `add` method to:

```
void add(int i) {
    System.out.println(5+i);
    System.out.println(5+this.i); //this will do the work for you
}
```

A good example of shadowing is used on class constructors:

```
public class SomeClass {
    int x;
    public SomeClass(int x) {
        //this.x refers to the x attribute
        //plain x refers to x parameter
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Follow up from comment:

> got it , but what happens if i have the same member as i in JavaTest2 ...and do the same this.i

This is called **hiding** and is well explained in Oracle's Java tutorial: [Hiding Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

Example:

```
class JavaTest2 extends JavaTest {
    int i = 10;
    void add(int i) {
        System.out.println(5+i);
        System.out.println(5+this.i); //this will add 5 to i attribute in JavaTest2
        System.out.println(5+super.i); //this will add 5 to i attribute in JavaTest
    }
}
```

Comment: got it , but what happens if i have the same member as i in JavaTest2 ...and do the same this.i

Comment: Then your `JavaTest2` will **hide** the attribute declared in `JavaTest` class.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the `i` you received as the parameter. Try `this.i`.

```
void add(int i)
{
    System.out.println(i + this.i);
}
```

This will print `7` in your example above.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 5 to the `add` method. To this 5 is 5 added and printed

```
System.out.println(5+i);
```

So nothing surprising here.

The `i` which is initialised in `JavaTest` is shadowed by the `i` in the method declaration. The most local variable gets used by definition. If you want the method to use the field `i` you could change your method like this:

```
void add(int j) {
    System.out.println(5+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your `add` method, the `i` variable from the super-class isn't visible. You're overriding it with a parameter that you've also called `i`.

Try replacing your `add()` method with this:

```
void add(int x)
{
    System.out.println(5+i);
}
```

The output will become 7. What you're doing now, effectively, is printing out `5+x`.

Answer (score 0):

The `i` inside `add` is the one from parameter not inherited `i` from the parent class

```
  void add(int i) <----------------+
  {                                |
      System.out.println(5 + i); --+

      System.out.println(5 + this.i);  --> member i
  }
```

Therefor after `add(5)`, it will print `5+5` -> `10`.

To indicate inherited `i`, try to use `this.i` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter in the add() function has the same name as the class attribute.

Rename your parameter and it should work:

```
void add(int someNumber)
{
     System.out.println(5+i); // result 7
     System.out.println(5+someNumber); // result 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local variable in scope (it is accessible from whereever you are referencing it), it will take the local one. Since you have one instance variable in the super-class (JavaTest) and a parameter in the add method, it will take the latter.

It is generally advisable to make all instance variables private unless otherwise required. On top of that, it is very bad practice to use the same names for local variables and instance variables (it think that's called shadowing).

Answer (score 0):

- This is a simple concept of `inheritance`.
- Where the `methods` and `instance variables` of a **super class** is inherited into the **base class.**
- `i` is an instance variable of JavaTest class which is being inherited by its base class.

  void add(int i) {

  ```
  System.out.println(5+i);  // i is already 5, so 5 + 5 = 10
  ```

  }