# How to override instance variables/methods in main?

Tags: java, inheritance

I want to access the instance variable `x` in the super class. 
I can't find a syntax for it.  Is this even possible?

```
public class SuperBoss {
    int x = 10;
}

public class Boss extends SuperBoss {
    int x = 2;

public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    Boss b = new Boss();
    System.out.println(b.x); //prints out 2, I want it to print out 10 
}
```

I've been trying to use the keyword "super" with no success.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16163412/1065197

Comment: Maybe: System.out.println(((SuperBoss)b).x);

Comment: @zgnilec check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16269227/1065197) and comments

Comment: @zgnilec  Dude, that's the most simplest and awesome answer lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Fields have compile-time binding. What you need is a cast to SuperBoss:

```
public class SuperBoss {
    int x = 10;
}

public class Boss extends SuperBoss {
    int x = 2;

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Boss b = new Boss();
        System.out.println(((SuperBoss)b).x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish zgnilec would have posted his comment as an answer since he recommended this solution first, but since you have the exact same solution, I accepted this one..lol
Thanks.

Comment: @KacyRaye If we're going by time, I was there before both of them.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis your answer is incorrect, it shows how to access super class field using an object of a super class rather than using an object of a subclass.

Comment: @tcb Do you know how to use a debugger? Take the code I posted and run it with a breakpoint at the `println()`, then take a look at the type of the objects. Assigning an instance to another type doesn't change the instance, it changes its interface (casting). We are doing the exact same thing, except you do it in one line, I do it in two.

Comment: @Sotirios Had I changed the value of the instance variable, your solution would not have worked.

Comment: @Luiggi I read every answer and understood each one.  What's wrong with this solution?  It lets me override methods which is more important to me.  I would never make instance variables public, and this solution was very straightforward.

Comment: @KacyRaye because you're learning, and I tend to teach people the right way to do things i.e. in Java Web Development, using scriptlets against EL+JSTL. This answer is a hack, and if you do this in real world apps, I can say that doing these things you will only earn the hate of coworker programmers and future programmers who have to maintain your code. Is wrong to not encapsulate variables? **YES**, is it wrong to hide the super class attributes in sub classes? It depends of its use. In this case, it is a **wrong** example. Still, is up to you how you will use the provided answers.

Comment: @KacyRaye I don't see what you're saying. Give an example.

Comment: @Sotirios If I did something like: ((SuperBoss)b).x = 1000;
And then used System.out.println(SuperBoss.x);
It would print out 10 and not 1000.

Comment: @KacyRaye that's the problem of using hacks and dropping encapsulation.

Comment: @KacyRaye That is incorrect syntax, and also wrong. Go to my example, try to change the `x` on `boss` and try changing it on `superBoss`. See what happens.

Comment: @KacyRaye last comment: you read all the answer and kept the worst.

Comment: @Sotirios Actually, your answer would have never worked because x in SuperBoss is not static.

Comment: @KacyRaye You really need to look at things more closely or actually try to run them. The class is called `SuperBoss`, the instance is called `superBoss`, lowercase `s`.

Answer (score 4):

It prints out `2` because your declaration of `int x = 2` in `Boss` is *hiding* the declaration of `x` in `SuperBoss`

Normally you would use the `super` keyword to explicitly access `public` fields of the superclass, this however won't work from the `static` context of the main method. You can define a small helper function that will get you the value of the superclass's `x`

```
public class Boss extends SuperBoss {
    int x = 2;

    public int getSuperX() {
        return super.x;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
       Boss b = new Boss();
       System.out.println(b.getSuperX()); //prints out 2, I want it to print out 10 
    }
}
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry, I had a solution posted, but forgot to click submit :|

Comment: I was about to post a similar solution using a `public int getSuperX()` method with the same method content =P. Now one more person did it.

Comment: Thanks for the advising a get method, Hunter.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell (and I should probably look in the JLS for the details), it is legal to access a shadowed non-private field with `super`, but only from within an instance method. So you could do this:

```
public class Boss extends SuperBoss {

    int x = 2;

    int getSuperX() {
        return super.x;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Boss b = new Boss();
        System.out.println(b.getSuperX());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `getSuperX()` method in your `Boss` class:

```
public class Boss extends SuperBoss {

    int x = 2;

    public int getSuperX() {
        return super.x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boss b = new Boss();
        System.out.println(b.getSuperX());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is going on is that the instance variable of `Boss` is hiding the instance variable of the same name in `SuperBoss`. You can temporarily cast your instance to the supertype class:

```
public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    Boss boss = new Boss();
    SuperBoss superBoss = boss;
    System.out.println(boss.x); //prints 2
    System.out.println(superBoss.x); //prints 10 
}
```

This is not recommended. For encapsulation reasons, your instance variables should not be visible, ie. should be private/protected. And probably should not have the same name as variables in parent classes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It is so nasty and I do not recommend it.

Comment: You don't recommend it but post it as answer and don't say **it is not recommended** anywhere. Also, this only leads to bad design, it can be used to show what you must not do in real world apps.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This is not code review. Hacky tricks some times do the trick.

Comment: *Hacky tricks* like this generates this kind of questions. The main problem still remains: **bad design**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza However, this does show some of java's functionality and people should be aware of how you can access things based on the declared type of an instance.

Comment: Heyy, I don't fully understand why this is a bad "trick," but I appreciate the answer nonetheless because it lets me see one more way of doing things.  I like when I've got options, and so long as I full understand those options, I feel like I can use them :)

Comment: @KacyRaye the problems with this solution: 1. Bad encapsulation. 2. Tight coupling (from subclass with super class). 3. Leaks on future maintenance.

Comment: @Luiggi Oh I see.  I used public instance variables just to keep things simple, but I can see where this would lead to problems now. Thanks for all your constructive criticism on other people's answers!

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you need to declare `x` as `protected` in the superclass, and not attempt to override it in the subclass:

```
public class SuperBoss {
    protected int x = 10;
}

public class Boss extends SuperBoss {
    // int x = 2;

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Boss b = new Boss();
        System.out.println(b.x);
    }
}
```

In practice, however, there is little need for `protected` data. It can cause almost as many problems as `public` data.  Better is:

```
public class SuperBoss {
    private int x = 10;

    protected int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

public class Boss extends SuperBoss {
    // int x = 2;

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Boss b = new Boss();
        System.out.println(b.getX());
    }
}
```